# How can I make input/select focus in PhoneGap faster?

Tags: performance, cordova, jqmobi

Clicking on input elements (text, texarea, select, etc) has a noticeable delay in PhoneGap...is there any way to overcome this?

I understand that the user might be dragging/scrolling when they touch the screen which is why the delay is there and I have been able to overcome this with anchors by using onTouchStart events instead of onClick, but I don't know how to apply the same thing to other inputs.

I'm using jqMobi (a stripped down jQuery framework which rocks!).

It doesn't appear as though you can call .focus() on input elements or .click() on select elements, which was what I tried by tapping into the onTouchStart event like this:

```
<input type="text" name="email" ontouchstart="$(this).focus();" />
<select name="country" ontouchstart="$(this).click();">...</select>
```

Any help would really be appreciated!!

---

The sluggishness is on the device, not in the browser. We're currently targeting iOS and I've experienced the sluggishness on the iPhone 4, 4s, iPad 2 and the new iPad.

Comment: Can you tell us how you tested your phonegap app? Through Browser? or Mobile?

Comment: are you using jqUi?  that has built in "click" capturing to get rid of the delay.  If not, you can look at the jq.touchLayer.js plugin which does all of that for you.  I'd be happy to help you figure it out outside of jqUi.

Comment: I used the onTouchStart event to eliminate the delay on anchor <a> clicks, but the problem has more to do with <input> and <select> elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jqUi of jqMobi then that should be already solved.

Otherwise you can activate the $.ui.touchLayer plugin which should solve that and other cross browser and touch related issues.

Comment: With jqMobi is there a particular class that needs to be added to an input to make it respond faster? Clicking anchors using the onclick event works great its just the delay in clicking a text/select input and that input actually getting focus that's causing the UX issue.

Answer (score 0):

How to Apply Touch event instead of click. when you are dynamically binding html to dom.

```
[1] href = "<a class='applymenutouch' data-ele='" + i + "' >";
[2] $('.applymenutouch').on('touchstart', function () { alert(render_submenu_link($(this).attr('data-ele'))); })
```